# How to use promises when a function returns an array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have a complex Node application that does not use Promises, but I have realized that I've got an async problem that needs to be solved, and Promises seem like one possible approach.  I have no experience with Promises, though, and I'm finding the learning curve challenging.

In order to maintain encapsulation and testability, the primary interface between one part of the application and another is a list of actions to be performed.  This is simply an array of objects with properties used by the calling function to execute the actions.  So, the first module is more abstract, simply specifying generic actions to be taken, while the calling module is a concrete implementation that executes the actions against a specific backend API.  In order to maintain encapsulation and testability, the generic module needs to remain unaware of the specific module.

The problem I have is that there is a sequence of asynchronous steps that now need to be determined by the generic module, where the later steps cannot occur until the earlier actions executed in the specific module have completed.  However, since the generic module cannot know about the specific module, it cannot execute the actions itself.  All it can do is return the actions to the specific module.

But the specific module needs to execute the actions and then followup with the other actions that the generic module has determined.

This is where I am stuck.  I don't know how to return a list of action objects, along with their thenable actions, from the generic module to the specific one.  I don't know if this is due to my lack of understanding of Bluebird, or if I am trying to do something that cannot be done with Bluebird.

It seems like one approach would be to add an afterExecution property to the actions, which would be the followup function to be called after the action completes.  However, this feels a lot like home-grown Promises, so I am reluctant to go that route.

If you are still able to follow this confusing scenario, what I am asking is how to return a list of actions that also have a "callback" function to be executed after the primary action object is handled.  Is that something Bluebird can handle?

---

**EDIT**:
After some sleep, I can hopefully illustrate what I am after.  Here is a stripped down version of what I currently have implemented.

**generic.js** (cannot know about **specific.js**):

```
function createActions() {
    var actions = []

    var action1 = {command:'buy', qty:100, symbol:'S', price:3.50}
    var self = this
    action1.afterwards = function() {
       self.setStopAndTarget()
    }
    actions.push(action1)
    // add some more actions

    return actions
}
```

**specific.js**:

```
Promise.method(function checkForTrades() {
    var actions = generic.createActions()
    actions.forEach(function(a) {
        if( a.command === 'buy' ) {
            buyStock(a.symbol, a.qty, q.price).then(function(a) {
                if( a.afterwards ) {
                    a.afterwards()
                }
            })
        }
    })
})
```

So, **specific.js** calls `createActions()` in **generic.js** to get a list of actions.  `actions` is an array of JSON objects, but, as you can see, I've also added a function to the `action` as a property named `afterwards`.

**specific.js** then processes the `actions`.  After an `action` completes, I use a `Promise` to then check for the existence of the property `afterwards`.  If it exists, I invoke it.

What I would really like to do is have the `then()` coded inside of **generic.js**, rather than **specific.js**, so that I don't have to create the `afterwards` property as part of the `action`.  But I could not figure out how to do that.

What I have works, but I'm pretty sure that Promises could do this without having to add `afterwards` to the `action`.

Also, if an array of actions comes back, I would like to know how to defer the `then()` action until all actions have completed.  I'm pretty sure that's just a matter of using `Promises.all`, but it would be helpful to see the syntax.

Thanks!

Comment: After reading this twice through Im finding this is a little hard to grasp. Example code or even a diagram maybe?

Comment: You say, "one part of the app" and then later you talk about "modules"--by "modules" you are referring to these two "parts"? Who is calling who here, and who is returning what to who?

Comment: I can't fault anyone who had a hard time following this.  It was written as the sun was coming up after a very long day and night.  I will edit the post with some code that should clear up what I was asking.  I appreciate your efforts at deciphering my incoherence.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question, but here are some ideas.

If you're telling me that you need to synchronize a set of responses before going to the next step, you could use [`Promise.all`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html) or [`Promise.join`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.join.html) in order to do that.

The difference between them is just the way you pass the arguments. `Promise.all` takes an array of thenables, while `Promise.join` takes a list of thenable arguments.

Both work the same way: the resulting promise will only resolve when ALL the input promises resolve. If any of them is rejected, the resulting promise will be rejected too.

So, if you have an array of asynchronous processes, all you have to do is create a promise for each one and then pass these promises to `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several patterns which could be relevant to this, depending on the details of what you are trying to accomplish.

Perhaps the most promising is a sort of co-routine like approach implemented using promises (when working with promises, please put the word "callback" out of your mind).

In this approach, the generic module would invoke a function in the specific module, which returns a promise for when it is done. The generic module then hangs its following execution steps off the promise returned from the specific module. Here's a really basic implementation:

```
function generic() {
  var specifics = [specific1, specific2, specific3];
  var promise = Promise.resolve();
  for (var i = 0; i < specifics.length; i++) {
    promise = promise.then(specifics[i]);
  }
  return promise;
}

function specific1() {
  return specific1_async_thing() . then(specific2_async_thing);
}
```

In other words, the way `specific1` "calls back" to the generic side is to return a promise to it, giving the generic side the means to know (via `then`) when to execute its next step.

The above logic would execute the generic steps in sequence--there are other approaches that would work for other scenarios, like kicking off all the specific guys together.

It might also be useful for you to consider async functions. They would allow the `generic` function to be rewritten as

```
async function generic() {
  var specifics = [specific1, specific2, specific3];
  for (var i = 0; i < specifics.length; i++) {
    await specifics[i];
  }
}
```